# Geddy.js - rendering partial views without layout, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, partial, geddy

Is it possible to render a partial view in Geddy.js without rendering the entire HTML page layout?

```
self.respond(model, {layout: false, template: 'app/views/users/_list'});
```

I've tried to do this with no success.
(Although the documentation says: "layout [false]: a flag to not use a layout file")

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can pass `false` into the layout, which will not use a layout from file.

http://geddyjs.org/documentation#controllers.respond

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I finally made an "empty" layout called `empty.html.ejs`:

```
<%- yield(); %>
```

Then I used it like this, in the appropriate controller action:

```
..., {layout: 'app/views/layouts/empty', ...
```

It seems to be a hack, but at least it is a working solution...